# Amazon AWS domain not working without www

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

I have website hosted on Amazon AWS and have created hosting zones for the domains.  However, for a particular domain (www.mohawkhonda.com) the website DNS can not be reached if we just type in mohawkhonda.com.  It required the www.  -  This is a weird issue esp on elastic beanstalk as there are no static ips.

What is the best solution to make sure both pull up perfectly?  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: You don't have a record in DNS for the non-www host.  You need to add that first.  Some providers allow you to do a CNAME to this, some don't.

Comment: Are you using Route53?

Comment: @MarkB yes I am.

Here is a copy of the Hosted Zones:

`
mohawkhonda.com.
A
ALIAS dealervenom.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com. (z117kps5gtrq2g)
No
-
mohawkhonda.com.
NS
ns-132.awsdns-16.com. 
ns-2022.awsdns-60.co.uk. 
ns-1415.awsdns-48.org. 
ns-552.awsdns-05.net.
-
-
172800
mohawkhonda.com.
SOA
ns-132.awsdns-16.com. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
-
-
900
www.mohawkhonda.com.
CNAME
mohawkhonda.com
-
-
300

`

Comment: Do you have two record sets, one for the naked domain and for www. in route53?

Comment: @Ashan I just posted the Hosted Zones

Answer (score 3):

If your naked domain works, for www.yourdomain.com just add a record "A" Alias(Yes) and set Alias Target to your naked domain (yourdomain.com).

Comment: It's the opposite.  The issue is that the naked domain doesn't work but the www. works.

Comment: Try to change your record www "CNAME" by "A" and select Alias "Yes" then select your naked domain from the list.

Comment: I tried doing this and then both the www and without www stopped working. :(

Answer (score 0):

The OPs pattern can also happen when no A record(s) is/are set for ns:

ns1.domainserver.tld    A    17.917.70.448

ns2.domainserver.tld    A    17.917.70.448